# How can I select given data in array?

Tags: c

```
int substance[5]={0.15, 0.8, 35.3, 401, 46};

printf("Please select the substance: (1)Oak (2)Glass (3)Lead (4)Copper (5)Steel)");
scanf("lf%", substance[0])
```

In the array, I have the data for different material,

I want the user to type 1-5 and select one of the material.
say, user select 2, the the following calculation will use number 0.8

Comment: So what have you tried and where is the problem? Also what is that `scanf` call supposed to do?

Comment: You have a confused mission: are you trying to select one of five materials, or are you trying to overwrite the property of Oak in the array? Moreover, the array as `int[]` is the wrong type: should be `double[]`. And `scanf("lf%", substance[0])` should be `scanf("lf%", &substance[0])` if that is the case.

Comment: `int substance[5]={0.15, 0.8, 35.3, 401, 46};` WFT?? Is your intent to force integer rounding within the initialization? There isn't a technical problem, but it looks bad....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some issues.

First, your `substance`-array should contain `double`-values, so its type should be `double`, too (not `int`).
Second, if you ask the user for input, store the input in a separate variable (not in the `substance`-array).
Try the following and use a debugger to see how a program behaves:

```
double substance[5]={0.15, 0.8, 35.3, 401, 46};

printf("Please select the substance: (1)Oak (2)Glass (3)Lead (4)Copper (5)Steel)");
int position=-1;
scanf("%d", &position);
double actualSubstance = -1;
if (position > 0 && position <= 5) {
  actualSubstance = substance[position-1];
}
// actualSubstance will contain the selected substance, or -1 if an invalid selection has been taken
```

Comment: typo: `"d%"` should be `"%d"` (in `scanf`)